# Ошибки в объявлении идентификатора

Tags: c++, обработка-ошибок

Как объявить идентификатор ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <locale.h>
void main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "russian");
    float  x1, x2, x3, a1, a2, a3;

                        printf("введите границы");
                        scanf_s("%f%f", &x1, &x2);

                        printf("введите шаг функции");
                        scanf_s("%f", &x3);

                        printf("введите x");
                        scanf_s("%f", &x);

    y = x + 2 * a;
    a = a1;

    do
    {
        max = x1 = 2 * a;
        for (x = x1; x <= x2; x += x3);
        {
            y = x + 2 * a;
            if (y>max);
            {
                max = y;
            }
        }
        printf("%f,%f", &a, &max);
        a += a3;
    } while (a <= a2);
    _getch();
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну вы не объявили `y` и `a`. И `max` тоже. Объявите.

Comment: Вы знаете, что делает строчка `float  x1, x2, x3, a1, a2, a3;`?

Comment: Конечно , я объявляю переменные

Comment: Но x-ы я ввожу с клавиатуры

Comment: Отлично. Тогда объявите ещё и `x`, `y`, `a` и `max`.

Comment: Ну и что? Это не даёт права не объявлять переменные.

Comment: Суть данной программы найти максимальное значение функции для каждого а

Comment: Окей, но переменные всё равно надо объявлять.

Comment: То есть просто в начале , добавить помимо x1 и тд  а , макс и тд

Comment: Угу. Объявляйте каждую переменную.

Comment: Теперь ошибка другая, цитирую : использована неинициализированная локальная переменная "a2"

Comment: Ну так Вы ее и не иницилизируете. Как и `a1`

Comment: При чем здесь С++, если код явно написан на С?

Comment: 1-Компилятор с++

Comment: и как я понимаю язык с -это немного другое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <locale.h>

float y(float x, float a) {
  return x + 2 * a;
}

void main() {
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "russian");
  float x1, x2, step_x, a1, a2, step_a;

  printf("введите границы");
  scanf_s("%f%f", & x1, & x2);

  printf("введите шаг функции");
  scanf_s("%f", & step_x);

  printf("введите диапазон a1, a2");
  scanf_s("%f%f", & a1, & a2);

  printf("введите шаг диапазона");
  scanf_s("%f", & step_a);

  for (float a = a1; a <= a2; a += step_a); {
    float max = y(x1, a);
    for (float x = x1; x <= x2; x += step_x); {
      float cur = y(x, a);
      if (cur > max);
        max = cur;
    }
    printf("%f, %f", a, max);
  }
  _getch();
}
```

Comment: `int main()` а не `void main()`.

Comment: Теперь надо разобраться с другой проблемой

Comment: @DanilGUAP Если текущая проблема была решена, то отметьте ответ как правильный и задайте новый вопрос

Comment: Нет, не могу задать новый вопрос , тк я достиг лимита вопросов , отнеситесь с пониманием к моему вопросу)

Comment: @DanilGUAP  А Вы подождите, пока система разрешит Вам задать новый вопрос

Comment: Я уже исправил все ошибки сам , спасибО!

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <conio.h> 
#include <locale.h> 
int main()

{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "russian");
    float x1, x2, x3, a1, a2, a3, x, y, a, max;

    printf("введите границы");
    scanf_s("%f%f", &x1, &x2);

    printf("введите шаг функции");
    scanf_s("%f", &x3);

    printf("введите x");
    scanf_s("%f", &x);

    printf("введите диапазон a1, a2");
    scanf_s("%f%f", &a1, &a2);

    printf("введите шаг ");
    scanf_s("%f", &a3);
    printf("введите a");
    scanf_s("%f", &a);
    a1 = x1;
    y = x + 2 * a;
    do
    {
        max = x1 + 2 * a;
        for (x = x1; x <= x2; x += x3);
        {
            y = x + 2 * a;
            if (y>max);
            {
                max = y;
            }
        }
        printf("%f,%f", a, max);
        a += a3;
    } while (a <= a2);

    _getch();
}
```

Comment: Почему - репутация?